# Best Books for Learning Modern Probability Theory

Tags: probability, probability-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am looking for a good recommendation for a book to learn modern probability theory. I have heard that perhaps Probability: Theory and Examples by Durrett is good, can anyone confirm this or recommend and alternative? Thanks!

Comment: I like Measure Theory and Probability Theory (by Krishna) very much.

Comment: How about "Modern Probability Theory" by B. R. Bhat?

Comment: Durrett has often been used as a textbook for graduate probability courses at UCLA. I think it seems good.

Comment: What is modern about probability theory?